# Ошибка - js invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

Подскажите что не так:

Вроде все нормально написал но получаю ошибку в присваивании ROI1, ROI2, ROISMALL

```
function calc() {
    var roi1 = $('.roi1');
    var roi2 = $('.roi2');
    var roismall = $('.roismall');

    var a = parseInt($('.calc-a').val());
    var b = parseInt($('.calc-b').val());
    var x = parseInt($('.calc-x').val());
    var y = parseInt($('.calc-y').val());
    var z = parseInt($('.calc-z').val());

    var ROI1 = z / (x * (2 – y/100)) – 1; //invalid or unexpected token
    var ROI2 = (z + a*b/100)/(x*(2-y/100));
    var ROISMALL = ROI2-ROI1;

    roi1.text(ROI1);
    roi2.text(ROI2);
    roismall.text(ROISMALL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в этой строчке минусы - не минусы.

```js
function calc() {
    var roi1 = $('.roi1');
    var roi2 = $('.roi2');
    var roismall = $('.roismall');

    var a = parseInt($('.calc-a').val());
    var b = parseInt($('.calc-b').val());
    var x = parseInt($('.calc-x').val());
    var y = parseInt($('.calc-y').val());
    var z = parseInt($('.calc-z').val());

    //var ROI1 = z / (x * (2 – y/100)) – 1; //invalid or unexpected token
    var ROI1 = z / (x * (2 - y/100)) - 1;
    var ROI2 = (z + a*b/100)/(x*(2-y/100));
    var ROISMALL = ROI2-ROI1;

    roi1.text(ROI1);
    roi2.text(ROI2);
    roismall.text(ROISMALL);
}

calc();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо)) Вот чего хрому не хватает чтобы подсвечивал в дебагере противный символ )) Так он просто дает ошибку которая не о чем не говорит, как поняли про минус если не секрет?

Comment: @user246535 Заподозрил, что дело в неправильном или неотображаемом символе, перепечатал строчку - заработало, дальше - методом исключения. Если приглядеться - видно, что черточка длиннее, чем должна быть. "... мелкоскопа не имеем, а у нас так глаз пристрелявши." Лесков "Левша"